# Nginx reverse proxy weird issue

Tags: azure, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I had configured Nginx as a reverse proxy to my Azure web app service and everything was working ok for many months. Recently however, I have simply changed the URL to which I am proxying to but now I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

To give more details, the below was my initial code that was working fine.

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name auth.invoicingapi.com;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $proxy_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port '443';
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host auth.invoicingapi.com;
      
      proxy_pass https://invoicingapi-auth.azurewebsites.net/;
  }
}
```

My nginx server is hosted on an Azure App Service container. It's acting as a reverse proxy to my https://invoicingapi-auth.azurewebsites.net Azure app service. This was working ok as navigating to auth.invoicingapi.com would successfully proxy to https://invoicingapi-auth.azurewebsites.net.

But recently I made the decision to host the https://invoicingapi-auth.azurewebsites.net website on Azure Container Apps, at a new url. So I updated the reverse proxy as below:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name auth.invoicingapi.com;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $proxy_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port '443';
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host auth.invoicingapi.com;
      
      #proxy_pass https://invoicingapi-auth.azurewebsites.net/;
      proxy_pass https://invoicingapi-auth.happydune-3770ec4b.germanywestcentral.azurecontainerapps.io;
  }
}
```

You can see all I changed was the new proxy_pass url. If you navigate to the new URL, the container app is working fine. But navigating to auth.invoicingapi.com is giving a 502 Bad Gateway error. How is this possible?

The Nginx logs don't seem to be much help. I'm seeing this error constantly:

```
[error] 28#28: *1129 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: <IP redacted>, server: auth.invoicingapi.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://<IP redacted>/favicon.ico", host: "auth.invoicingapi.com", referrer: "https://auth.invoicingapi.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I needed to add proxy_ssl_server_name and proxy_http_version to my location block.

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name auth.invoicingapi.com;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $proxy_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port '443';
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host auth.invoicingapi.com;
      
      #proxy_pass https://invoicingapi-auth.azurewebsites.net/;
      proxy_pass https://invoicingapi-auth.happydune-3770ec4b.germanywestcentral.azurecontainerapps.io;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
}
```